# Why Microsoft framework has asp.net life cycle events?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I got this question in an interview.

Why Microsoft framework has asp.net life cycle events, instead of this, we can write everything in single event. Seriously I too dont know why Microsoft have so many events? and what is the advantage of it.

Could anyone help me to understand the benefits of distributing the process among the events?

Comment: I still can't believe Tom Cruise going for an interview and being asked about this :-) Anyways, the whole design is event based. So all the required things are done in events. With MVC is has moved away from it. Each event has some role to play and you can use one of them depending upon requirement

Comment: there wouldn't be ways to customize it if it was in a single method.

Comment: @A3006 Next Mission Impossible movie will be interesting..........

Answer (score 2):

The [webforms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/) were designed to mimic desktop applications, so that it was easier for desktop developers to enter the web world.

As a part of this, an control structure representing the page was needed, plus event handling (onclick handlers and such). To support this in the web world, the page lifecycle was introduced. This enabled developers to influence things at particular stages.